# Extract values from array element containing multiple data fields

Tags: php, arrays, element

An incoming data feed is in the form of an array. However, each array element contains multiple data fields (both field name and field data). The sample below shows the content of each array element. Using PHP, how do I extract the field names and the associated data?

Thanks for your assistance!

```
stdClass Object (
    [Cancelled] =>
    [MessageID] => 999999
    [Queued] =>
    [ReferenceID] => FRIDAY
    [SMSError] => NoError
    [SMSIncomingMessages] => stdClass Object (
        [SMSIncomingMessage] => stdClass Object (
        [FromPhoneNumber] => 1999999999
        [IncomingMessageID] => 0byyyyyyy 
        [Message] => 45-64-07
        [ResponseReceiveDate] => 2012-01-07
    )
)
[Sent] => 1
[SentDateTime] => 2012-01-07)
```

Comment: See this similar post which answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value

Comment: Can you recopy the output of the array elements, maintaining whitespace, and use the `{}` button instead of `"` to format the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't exactly an array, but an object instead, so you have to access it using pointers. I'll show a couple examples:
In this example, I'll call your output `$output`

If this were an array, you would call elements like this:

```
echo $output['MessageID'];
echo $output['SMSIncomingMessages']['SMSIncomingMessage']['IncomingMessageID'];
```

But since this is an stdClass Object, you'll have to access it like this:

```
// will echo 999999
echo $output->MessageID;
```

It's also the same with multi-dimensions:

```
// will echo 0byyyyyyy
echo $output->SMSIncomingMessages->SMSIncomingMessage->IncomingMessageID;
```

You can still loop through the object like you would an array, but when you access the elements of the array, they still have to be accessed using a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used your method plus a loop and was able to extract all the required data.

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out for you :)
Please mark the question as answered be selecting the checkmark under the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This function will sort multidimensional arrays:

```
function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) {
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}


array_sort_by_column($array, 'order');
```